# Fazer append numa linha específica de um arquivo texto

Tags: php, laravel, arquivo

Bom dia, eu tenho uma função que faz um append em determinada linha do meu arquivo xml.

```
function addInFile($file, $lineNumber, $content)
{
    $fileTemp = "$file.bak";
    $currentLine = 0;

    $fpRead = fopen($file, 'r');
    $fpWrite = fopen($fileTemp, 'w');

    try {
        if ($fpRead) {
            while (($linha = fgets($fpRead)) !== false) {
                if ($currentLine == $lineNumber) {
                    $linha .= $content . PHP_EOL;
                }

                fwrite($fpWrite, $linha);
                $currentLine += 1;
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $err) {
        echo $err->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    } finally {
        fclose($fpRead);
        fclose($fpWrite);
        unlink($file);
        rename($fileTemp, $file);
    }
}
```

Só que eu preciso salvar meu arquivo fora do root do projeto laravel, eu configurei o `config/filesystem.php` para receber um disco que eu chamei de public

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('../../../public_html/xmls'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Meu problema é que eu não sei como transformar o `fopen, fgets, fclose, unlink, rename`, etc... com o `Storage::disk() do laravel`. Caso alguém possa me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Parece não haver função específica no Laravel para fazer um append numa linha específica. O exemplo que postou parece já fazer isso e normalmente isso é o suficiente. Não tem o que modificar. Talvez, no máximo, uma normalização, redução de códigos, otimização, etc. Mas não tem muito o que fazer pois não há algo equivalente descrito nas documentações do Laravel. Talvez `File::Get()`, que retorna o arquivo inteiro e então fazer um `explode()` nas quebras de linha. O que daria na mesma do que está fazendo, só que de um jeito mais zuado.

Comment: Como está lidando com XML, poderia considerar o uso do SimpleXML, consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: Na função fwrite() eu passo 2 argumentos, o content e a linha que eu quero que seja feito o append. O que eu preciso saber é se o Storage do Laravel tem uma função que faça isso.

Comment: Como comentei acima, não encontrei nada na documentação. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver.

O php abre os arquivos que estão fora do root do laravel, a unica coisa que eu precisei fazer foi passa o path completo do arquivo.

Em uma função criada em outra classe, ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
public function test(){
      $url = Storage::disk('public')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
      $fileManager->addInFile($url . $path, 7, $content);
}
```